# My system is constantly processing something, heating up my laptop

Tags: drivers, gpu

My system heats up when running Ubuntu, with no major processing tasks. I also run Windows 10, on the same machine, and it never heats up when on Windows, so we can rule out hardware issues. My best guess is a driver issue, since this problem started after I fiddled with my system in order to emulate a Nvidia GPU on AMD Radeon, using Ocelot, but I undid all my changes, and the problem persists.

Or any way to check which driver my system is using for graphics card?

My Resource Monitor Screenshot:

[image: Resource Monitor Screenshot]

My `top` result (it says user root using 48% processing):

```
top - 23:17:25 up  3:15,  1 user,  load average: 3.10, 3.11, 2.93
Tasks: 346 total,   2 running, 279 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 15.5 us, 20.1 sy,  0.1 ni, 63.4 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.8 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 12209596 total,  3167008 free,  3717188 used,  5325400 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  7155104 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
  374 root      20   0  220908 178912   3140 S  48.0  1.5  25:38.91 systemd-ud+ 
 4948 ashutosh  20   0 1162840 137192 103660 S   3.3  1.1   4:00.39 Xorg        
26005 ashutosh  20   0 2855536 381020 151472 S   2.6  3.1   4:27.62 firefox     
 5308 ashutosh  20   0 3851468 264376  75324 S   2.3  2.2   3:00.62 gnome-shell 
    1 root      20   0  226204  10040   6768 S   2.0  0.1   1:26.18 systemd     
 4788 root      20   0   29012    840    780 R   1.7  0.0   0:00.05 modprobe    
18343 ashutosh  20   0  723704  39712  30020 S   1.7  0.3   0:07.60 gnome-term+ 
 8648 ashutosh  20   0 2112580 233300 140332 S   1.3  1.9   3:30.49 Web Content 
26421 ashutosh  20   0 2184448 458740  90536 S   1.3  3.8   3:24.41 WebExtensi+ 
  339 root      19  -1  266948 137392 132132 S   1.0  1.1   0:41.54 systemd-jo+ 
 1328 root      20   0   48000   5524   2348 S   1.0  0.0   0:58.36 systemd-ud+ 
14747 _apt      20   0   81832   8772   7788 S   1.0  0.1   0:25.84 http        
19207 ashutosh  20   0 5137248 660948  53060 S   1.0  5.4   3:30.89 java        
 1698 root      20   0 1803284  35956  27112 S   0.7  0.3   0:37.50 libvirtd    
 2604 root      20   0   48000   4772   1600 S   0.7  0.0   0:44.92 systemd-ud+ 
 4701 root      20   0   48000   6616   3416 S   0.7  0.1   0:43.52 systemd-ud+ 
21966 root      20   0  780024  31784  17092 S   0.7  0.3   0:33.25 snapd
```

`udevadm monitor` result:

```
ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

UDEV  [4527.590214] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4527.605280] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4527.720709] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4527.721492] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4527.721563] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4527.721932] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4527.721984] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4527.736603] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4527.744206] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4527.746470] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4527.759300] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4527.774551] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4527.885168] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4527.885935] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4527.886011] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4527.886380] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4527.886433] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4527.900224] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4527.902492] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4527.911873] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4527.926199] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4527.940766] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.048687] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4528.049406] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4528.049477] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.049817] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4528.049866] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4528.066313] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4528.072171] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4528.075653] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4528.088961] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4528.090611] add      /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4528.101611] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4528.112995] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4528.245592] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4528.246903] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4528.247002] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.247526] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4528.247599] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.260227] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4528.262239] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4528.272641] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4528.288292] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4528.300851] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.402297] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4528.403053] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4528.403126] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.403492] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4528.403542] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.416235] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4528.419266] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4528.428287] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4528.443380] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4528.456770] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.555878] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4528.556659] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4528.556739] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.557108] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4528.557160] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.572199] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4528.572770] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4528.582049] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4528.595829] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4528.610358] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.713648] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4528.714387] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4528.714461] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.714798] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4528.714856] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.728260] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4528.731368] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4528.741057] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4528.751104] add      /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4528.754985] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4528.765928] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4528.769766] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.898017] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4528.898776] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4528.898852] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.899224] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4528.899274] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4528.912328] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4528.913607] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4528.923057] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4528.938895] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4528.951204] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4529.053251] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4529.053993] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4529.054067] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4529.054430] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4529.054482] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4529.068218] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4529.069977] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4529.079324] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4529.094377] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4529.107379] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4529.210655] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4529.211399] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4529.211476] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4529.211834] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4529.211881] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4529.224166] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4529.226843] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4529.237124] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4529.252801] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4529.265856] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4529.366827] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4529.367552] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4529.367626] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4529.367955] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4529.368055] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4529.383073] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4529.384195] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4529.392245] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4529.404878] add      /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4529.408027] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4529.419792] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4529.425247] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4529.567700] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4529.568567] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4529.568670] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4529.569048] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4529.569120] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4529.585039] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4529.595090] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4529.600162] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4529.609379] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4529.623199] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4529.763077] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4529.764182] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4529.764299] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4529.764784] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4529.764865] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4529.780412] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4529.788177] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4529.790516] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4529.803121] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4529.818311] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4530.027936] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4530.029017] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4530.029131] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4530.029612] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4530.029691] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4530.045657] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4530.052206] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4530.057300] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4530.070458] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4530.086839] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4530.206142] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4530.206865] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4530.206955] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4530.207302] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4530.207336] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4530.223105] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4530.224214] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4530.234185] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4530.243977] add      /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4530.247910] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4530.259226] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4530.262211] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4530.391019] add      /module/nvidia (module)
KERNEL[4530.391904] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4530.391982] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4530.392415] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
KERNEL[4530.392468] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
UDEV  [4530.408068] add      /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4530.418642] add      /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
KERNEL[4530.420181] remove   /module/nvidia (module)
UDEV  [4530.431689] remove   /kernel/slab/:0012288 (slab)
UDEV  [4530.445422] remove   /bus/pci/drivers/nvidia-nvswitch (drivers)
```

My `lspci -k` and `dmesg` output, `dmesg` output just repeats forever as shown below:

```
[ 7645.281540] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[ 7645.295973] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 240
[ 7645.296392] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[ 7645.296614] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 240
[ 7645.462797] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[ 7645.478302] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 240
[ 7645.478703] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter found!
[ 7645.478886] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 240
ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ man lspci
ashutosh@ashutosh-Lenovo-G50-80:~$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI
    Kernel driver in use: bdw_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 5500
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Broadwell-U Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl
04:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

Comment: For start, please see `top` or `htop` to find out which processes are keeping your system busy.

Comment: As for how to check which drivers your system is using: see `man lspci`. `lspci -k` (or `lspci -v`, which implies `-k`) may help you.

Comment: If `systemd-ud+` in your `top` output stands for `systemd-udevd`, I would be curious to know the output of `udevadm monitor`. 25 minutes of CPU time over 3 hours of total system uptime look rally unusual.

Comment: @fra-san check this out --->https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2333906, this is my issue. Running dmesg shows Nvlink Core is being initialized and then NVRM:No NVIDIA graphics driver found, and this repeats forever, it's a loop with udev. I tried restarting udev, doesn't help. Also, I don't have a Nvidia Graphics card

Comment: Glad to see you issue is now solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nvidia drivers are causing problems with Ubuntu 18.04+. Uninstall Nvidia drivers and everything related to it. This solved my problem:

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`